# What's the conventional meaning of an arc over a letter?

Tags: statistics

While reading the introductory part talking about Bayesian statistics in the [Probabilistic ML Intro.](https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book1.html) book (4.6 in the version 2022-08-08), I encountered symbols with arc over letters like these: $\overset{\smile}{\alpha}$, $\overset{\frown}{\beta}$.
(probably written with incorrect symbols, but the looking is quite similar)

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw8ev.png) of relevant content.

I'm wondering what such symbols conventionally mean.

Comment: See the Appendix A.8.3. in the text.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thank you for pointing out, very helpful.

Comment: Which essentially says $\overset{\smile}{\phi}$  is the prior value of the hyperparameters and 
$\overset{\frown}{\phi}$ their posterior value.  (You can use your `\overset{\smile}{\phi}` for $\overset{\smile}{\phi}$ or `\breve{\phi}` for $\breve{\phi}$ for the first)